# How I connect to my localhost from external devices

Tags: apache, localhost, server

I'm trying to connect my Android device to my localhost server (Apache)...
I've read tons of possible solutions here and none of them had helped me yet.

I created a WLAN with VirtualRouter and I've been connected my device to it.
Using another server (Node.js) I'm able to connect from my mobile devices. But if try with Apache server he can't find anything and Chrome Browser give me `CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

I've tried to change listening ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, I've tried to change the `<Directory` in order to allow external connection.

Usefull stuff:

- The server Apache is listening at 80port like the following code: `Listen 80`
- Windows Firewall has been disabled

I really don't know what to do, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to specify more information like the configuration of your apache server and your firewall settings.

Comment: I disabled my firewall and idk what other information you need for my apache server... I've got EasyPHP14vc9 and inside that was Apache

Comment: I have no idea about those "convenience" packages around, I can only say something about a normal apache http server. That comes with a configuration (typically inside `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/httpd`). It should be configured to listen on port 80 (default for http) and all network devices. Then test from your computer to open port 80 (you can use the `telnet` utility for that). If that works, then there is just the network layer left to check. I cannot say anything about your "virtual router" (no idea what that is), but if node.js can be reached that step should be fine.

Comment: My apache server's listening on 80 and when i try on my "computer"-browser everything is fine, if i type my network address i'm able to reach my Apache-server... 
But if try with my phone it give to me the error CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: OK, sounds like a network routing problem or a blocked port (firewall). That node.js server was operated on the same address in the same network? That should say that the routing is fine, so where is the difference?

Comment: Node use a different port (3000) but it stay in the same network under the same address with apache...

My firewall is stopped and that's why I able to reach Node.js server if it is started...

Comment: The port is irrelevant for routing questions. That is why I compare node.js and apache here. So back to the network devices and your apache binding... you sure you did restart the http server after changing the configuration? could you post that part of the configuration? Usually you just leave away the ip address when you want to listen on all devices: `Listen 80`

Comment: Yeah sure:
[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/DCf2wzjK)

However i restarted the server after every change.

Comment: As writte above: leave away the ip address, just use `Listen 80`.

Comment: Nothing changed...
[listen 80](http://pastebin.com/agzvKY6S)

Comment: No idea then. According to your answers the network routing works fine, the server listens on the port ans replies,, it binds to all interfaces, no firewall blocks access. nothing more I can think of. Something in the http servers error log file? Sorry, no other idea. Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Since you're the only person in this world that now is helping me, let me make a report: I'm currently under windows, I've disabled windows firewall and defender,I've runned VirtualRouterManager (is a software that allow you to make your pc like an AP, you can also share connection with the other devices, but that's not my case), I've started EasyPHP and so also Apache and MySQL.[Here](http://pastebin.com/a5fLKWbt) you can find my Apache Error Log. If i try to call my server by the WLAN network from my pc everything works fine, but if i try to call my server by the same WLAN from my phone erro

Comment: Although I do not use all the components you mention I can very well follow your setup. As said before I see no fundamental issue, otherwise I would have pointed it out. Sorry! About the error log file: don't you think you should fix all those issues when starting up the php engine? Not that this issue here is connected, but it masically means you have no modules at all loaded in your php engine. You obviously have a dependency issue. Which indeed is hard to prevent and solve on an MS-Windows platform...

Comment: I really don't know how to fix them... I'm a designer and i really don't need that things, i just need a server that could be called by every devices connected to the WLAN

Comment: Let's take a different approach: what do you need that "virtual router" for? If both your server system and the phone are connected to the same network, then that should be fine. you just need to know the IP of the server system. (tripple check it!)

Comment: Where i need to execute my project i don't have any network at all... That's why i need Virtual Router... But i don't think this is the problem, because you remember that node works fine.

Comment: @arkascha Never mind, is an EasyPHP/Apache/Don'tKnowWhat but with xampp everything works fine... So i'm going to use that.

Comment: OK, great you found a solution. Just one hint: I again and again hear endless problems with those "convenience" packages around. Why don't people use the real packages? Then you have an unaltered, original software, precise documentation and many people able to help... But as said: great you can finally start! Have fun!